# Trying to make flash cards in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.5

I just recently started with python and was trying to make some sort of flash cards. I did this by making a text file inside note pad and just writing some simple math problems. The problems were written like this.

1 + 1 = ???

2

2 + 2 = ???

4

8 x 4 = ???

32

then my code was this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

x = 0
f=open('cardsss.txt').readlines()
while x < 6:
    line = f
    print(line[x])
    answer = input()
    if answer == line[x+1]:
        print ('Correct')
    else:
        print ('Wrong')
    x = x + 2


print ("Done")
```

The problem is that when i put the answer in, it always says that what ever i put in is wrong, and i can not figure out why.

Where i would get a screen like this

```
1 + 1 = ???

2
Wrong
2 + 2 = ???

4
Wrong
8 x 4 = ???

32
Wrong
Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines containing the answers end with a new line character `\n`. You need to *strip* the new line character off the lines you're reading from the file to make the items match:

```
if answer == line[x+1].strip():
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and fixed the problem i was having! Just never knew of that being the problem or the .strip() code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
TESTS_NUM = 3

with open('cardsss.txt') as f:
    for _ in range(TESTS_NUM):
        line = next(f)
        print(line)
        answer = input("Your answer: ")
        right_answer = next(f)
        if answer.strip() == right_answer.strip():
            print("Correct")
        else:
            print("Wrong")

print("Done")
```

This solution works if the file 'cardsss.txt' doesn't contain empty lines.

Comment: This worked, but just wondering why did you put the TEST_NUM = 3 in there, like what does it do?

Comment: That was just an example. You could solve it using the loop `while True:` and leave it if `next(f)` provides `None` as a line that means the end of file I think.